# Link to a working webRTC library for Android

Tags: android, webrtc, android-security

Google play have a new error/warning from the last days about the WebRTC library that I use. I use this library for almost a year.

```
google-webrtc-1.0.32006.aar
```

My app is still available but they ask to update the library, which usually means that they will block apps with this library it in the future.

this is the message

```
*Error : Vulnerable WebRTC versions
Your app uses a bad version of WebRTC, which contains security vulnerabilities.*
```

I have changed to the library that was updated 3 months ago, implementation `'ch.threema:webrtc-android:100.0.0'`
but it also did not pass their security note and the warning is still there.

They ask to re-compile and use new a webRTC library
[link to explanation](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/12577537)

I have tried to compile on Windows 10 - but it needs many dependencies which collide one with each other(clang/c++/different version of visual studio).

Is there a link to direct download or a gradle link (implementation)?
Good tutorial will be also appreciated - until now I found only non updates ones.

[image]

Comment: I would say that you need an ubuntu if you decide to build webrtc... maybe the windows ubuntu subsystem is enough to do it but I've never tried it, last time I build it (8 years ago) I used an ubuntu via VirtualBox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest release notes available point to version 105
https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/release-notes.md

But in this site it seems that there is also an 106 version
https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/branches which seem more updated!

I also found that guy https://github.com/rno/webrtc who claims to have the latest build available ie. 106!

So you can try:

```
'com.dafruits:webrtc:106.0.0'
```