# Vulnerable WebRTC Versions Error On Play Store

Tags: android, webrtc, webrtc-android

I'm using [webrtc android](https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/android/). After some version upload on play store, it's a while the play store shows me an error:

> Vulnerable WebRTC Versions: Your app uses a bad version of WebRTC, which contains security vulnerabilities.

Here is the version that I'm using `org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006`.
Are there any updates on this library?
If not, please suggest me an alternative for the Android native WebRTC library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link to a working webRTC library for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74128110/link-to-a-working-webrtc-library-for-android)

Comment: It worked thanks! But I had to do some migrations. Changing `addStream` to `addTrack` and observing it in `onAddTrack` instead of `onAddStream`.

Comment: Can you please let me know what migrations you did to fix this ? I'm facing this issue and not finding solution to fix kit

Comment: Sure, I'm setting it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has helped me: [Link to a working webRTC library for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74128110/link-to-a-working-webrtc-library-for-android). So I've changed my import to `com.dafruits:webrtc:113.0.0` and did some migrations. The main changes were turning `addStream` to `addTrack` and observing it in `onAddTrack` instead of `onAddStream`.

Comment: Thank you, only "Changing addStream to addTrack and observing it in onAddTrack instead of onAddStream" worked for you or you made any other changes too? Please let me know , it will be of great help to me.

Comment: As I remember, it was ok. Maybe a little syntax changes more... Let me know if you have a problem after your change.

Comment: Yeah, i still have the same issue .. i even removed addStream functions.. but still i'm getting this issue ..Not sure why i'm still facing this

Comment: Have you followed the link to change your library?